# Rotate a list in scheme

Tags: scheme

(rotate '(a b c d e)) should return ( (a b c d e) (b c d e a) (c d e a b) (d e a b c) (e a b c d) )

Here I have implemented the logic in shceme but i am facing problem can anyone help me out sovling this

Here is my code

```
(define (rotate lst)
  (define (iter l cycles result)
    (cond 
      ((= cycles 0) (cons lst result))
      ((< cycles 0) result)
      (else         (let ((cycled (cycle l)))
                      (iter cycled (- cycles 1) (append result (list cycled)))))))
  (iter lst (- (length lst) 1) ()))


(rotate '(a b c d e))
```

Comment: So what does your current code do?  What is wrong? What does it output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't that far:

```
(define (rotate lst)
  (define (iter lst cycles res)
    (cond
      ((= cycles 0) (reverse res))
      (else         (iter (append (cdr lst) (list (car lst))) 
                          (- cycles 1) 
                          (cons lst res)))))
  (iter lst (length lst) null))
```

- No need to make the distinction between cycles = 0, cycles > 0 and cycles < 0; one base case and one recursive case are enough
- What is `(cycle l)`? Is it defined somewhere else?

Comment: (define (rotate lst)
  (define (iter lst cycles res)
    (if (= cycles 0)
        (reverse res)
        (iter (append (cdr lst) (list (car lst))) 
              (- cycles 1) 
              (cons lst res))))
 (iter lst (length lst) ())) This gives my desierd output

Comment: @user3071665 Those are equal except you need `(define null '())` in @uselpa's version and your comment has a bare `()` that needs to be quoted. You replaced `cond` with `if`, but they are exactly the same. In fact, in most implementations `cond` is syntax-rules that end up as `if` just like `and` and `or`.

Comment: @user3071665 I would use `if` too, but I tried to stay close to the OP's code so that he can easily spot the differences. Just can't get myself to call a list `l` ;-)